# delay of boolean vector in python

Tags: python, boolean, delay

Hi I'm new to coding in python and I would like some feedback how to delay a boolean vector signal on the phase where true goes to false with the defined delay of [delay] samples.

Is there a nice coding example out there for this? Or where did I do the mistake in the code?

```
def delay_bool_signal(x, delay):
    xtmp = x
    dly = 0
    for i in range(1,len(xtmp)):
        if xtmp[i]==0 and xtmp[i-1]==1:
            dly = dly + 1
            if dly <= delay
                xtmp[i] = 1
            else:
                dly = 0
    return xtmp
```

Example vector could look like this...

```
BooleanVec = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Delay = 2
```

Expected output

```
BoolVecDel = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: share some input and output examples so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put colon after if condition in line number : 7 of your sample code, that's why you got syntax incorrect error.

Change that line

```
if dly <= delay
```

to

```
if dly <= delay:
```

And i check it it's working fine and you got your expected output.